# "Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead" with slash commands using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an economy bot on Discord. I finished with the embeds and ActionRows for the transfer part; however, when I do try to run the `/transfer` command; I get:

`Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead`

This comes from the `.js` file `interactionCrt.js` which I'm using to create the interactions;

```
const { Events } = require("discord.js");
const profileModel = require("../models/profileSchema.js");

module.exports = {
    name: Events.InteractionCreate,
    async execute(interaction) {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

        let userData;

        try {
            userData = await profileModel.findOne({userId: interaction.user.id});
            
            if(!userData) {
                userData = await profileModel.create({
                    userId: interaction.user.id,
                    serverId: interaction.guild.id
                })
            }

        } catch(err) {
            console.error(`[ERROR] Failed to get userData. Details: ${err}`);
        }
        
        const cmd = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!cmd) {
            console.error(`[ERROR] No command with name ${interaction.commandName} found.`);
            return;
        }

        try {
            await cmd.execute(interaction, userData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`[ERROR] Error occured while executing ${interaction.commandName}, details: ${err}`);

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting no other errors in the console, and this is what I have in the `transfer.js` script;

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ActionRowBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("transfer")
        .setDescription("Send currency to another user")
        .setDescriptionLocalizations({
            tr: "Başka bir kullanıcıya bakiye gönder"
        })
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName("target")
                .setDescription("Username to send currency to")
                .setDescriptionLocalizations({
                    tr: "Bakiye gönderilecek kullanıcının adı"
                })
            )
        .addIntegerOption(option =>
            option.setName("amount")
                .setDescription("Amount to send")
                .setDescriptionLocalizations({
                tr: "Gönderilecek miktar"
                })
            ),
    async execute(interaction, userData) {
       //console.log(interaction);
       const target = interaction.options.getMember("target");
       const amount = interaction.options.getInteger("amount");
       
       const { balance } = userData;

       if (balance >= amount) {
        const ENembed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0x015a32)
            .setTitle("Transfer Currency")
            .setDescription(":warning: This action is **IRREVIRSABLE**. You cannot get your currency back after its been transferred by any means whatsoever.")
            .addFields(
                {name: "Sender", value: (`<@${interaction.user.id}`), inline: true},
                {name: "Recipient", value: (`<@${target.user.id}>`), inline: true},
                {name: "Amount", value: (`**${amount}**`)},
            )
            .setFooter("ordekonomi")
    
        const TRembed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor(0x015a32)
            .setTitle("Bakiye Aktarma")
            .setDescription(":warning: Bu eylem **GERİ ALINAMAZ**. Bakiye aktarıldıktan sonra, geri almak imkansızdır.")
            .addFields(
               {name: "Gönderen", value: (`<@${interaction.user.id}`), inline: true},
               {name: "Alıcı", value: (`<@${target.user.id}>`), inline: true},
               {name: "Miktar", value: (`**${amount}**`)},
           )
            .setFooter("ordekonomi")

           let approve;
           let cancel;

           if (interaction.locale == "tr") {
                approve = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId("approve")
                    .setLabel("Onayla")
                    .setEmoji("white_check_mark")
                
                cancel = new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId("cancel")
                    .setLabel("İptal Et")
                    .setEmoji("x")
           } else {
                approve = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("approve")
                .setLabel("Approve")
                .setEmoji("white_check_mark")
        
                cancel = new ButtonBuilder()
                .setCustomId("cancel")
                .setLabel("Cancel")
                .setEmoji("x")
           }


           const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(approve, cancel)

    
           if (interaction.locate == "tr") {
                interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [TRembed],
                    components: [row]
                })
           } else {
                interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [ENembed],
                    components: [row]
            })
           }


       } else {

        await interaction.deferReply({
            ephemeral: true
        })
    
        if (interaction.locale == "tr") {
            
            await interaction.editReply(inlineCode(`Göndereceğiniz miktar bakiyenizden düşüktür. Güncel bakiyeniz: ${balance}`));

        } else {

            
            await interaction.editReply(inlineCode(`Your balance is lower than the amount you wish to send. Your current balance is: ${balance}`));
        }
       }

      
    }
}
```

This is the file structure of the main folder;

```
--- economybot
 --- cmds
  bal.js
  daily.js
  ping.js
  transfer.js

 --- events
  interactionCrt.js
  ready.js

 --- models
  profileSchema.js

 --- node_modules
  ...

.env
deploy-commands.js
index.js
package-lock.json
package.json
```

I tried running the `deploy-command.js` script again, however; the error still presisted. Other commands that I have registered, such as `/bal`, `/daily`, `/ping` still work fine. It's only affecting the `/transfer` command.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of discord.js, the `.setFooter()` method now requires an "`EmbedFooterData`" data type instead of a string, which was depreciated a few versions ago.

Now, footer text is defined like so:

```
.setFooter({ text: "ordekonomi" })
```

See the [Documentation on the EmbedFooterData](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/EmbedFooterData) for more info.